# Bind Dictionary inside a for loop

Tags: c#, blazor

Player.Scores is a Dictionary<int, int?>. This code renders the correct value from the dictionary. But when the input value changes, hole variable is the same as the for loop ended at. If the course has 18 holes, the loop ends when reaching 19. All bindings goes to player.Scores[19] and that adds an extra key to the dictionary.

How do I bind the dictionary to it's key when inside a loop?

```
    <tbody>
        @for (int hole = 1; hole <= Course.Holes; hole++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@hole</td>
                @foreach (var player in Players)
                {
                    <td><input @bind="player.Scores[hole]" /></td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: it's not `foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int>par in Players.Scores){ <input @bind="Players.Scores[par.Key]"/>}`?

Comment: @Eliseo - that is another solution but it requires a sorted Dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@for (int hole = 1; hole <= Course.Holes; hole++)
{
    int holeCopy = hole;  // let holeCopy be captured instead of hole
    <tr>
        <td>@hole</td>
        @foreach (var player in Players)
        {
            <td><input @bind="player.Scores[holeCopy]" /></td>
        }
    </tr>
}
```

`@bind` uses a lambda function when it is compiled to C#.

The problem is called 'capturing the loop var', you can google that.

And it won't hurt to use `<tr @key="hole">`